# How to model a Table-Per-Type inheritance in Laravel's Eloquent?

Tags: inheritance, laravel, orm, eloquent, table-per-type

For example, how can I model in Eloquent entities this database hierarchy, so I can automatically create an automobile entry when creating an car or truck:

```
- automobile
  id (PK)
  color, etc...

- car
  id (PK, automobile.id FK)
  doors, etc...

- truck
  id (PK, automobile.id FK)
  axis, etc...
```

Answer (score 2):

You may look into this relations http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#polymorphic-relations

These polymorphic relations allow you to model this use case. I don't know if on creation a entry for  car is created but you can create it easily by yourself. Hope this helps.

EDIT:

To create such a relation, the automobile table would get two new columns for example `automobile_id` and `automobile_type` important for those columns are the postfixes `_id` and `_type`. Your model would now look like this.

```
- automobile
  id(PK)
  color, etc...
  automobile_id
  automobile_type

- car
  id(PK)
  doors, etc...
```

In your automobile class you would now add a function which needs to be named according to the prefix you chose in the table in this case "automobile":

```
<?php

class Automobile extends Eloquent {

   ...

   public function automobile() {
      return $this->morphTo()
   }

}
```

When you create a new entity you put the id of the car into `automobile_id = 1` and you provide `automobile_type` with the class name of your eloquent model for car. In this case it would be `Car` I think. For a creation workflow I would suggest you allow to fill the fields of both the automobile and the car and first input the car entity into the database retrieve the columns id and fill it into `automobile_id`.

Comment: It would help more if you pasted relevant parts from the link into the question.